# FTPClient Pool - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, connection-pooling, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I am writing a Rest Service that connects to an FTP server to read some files, then do some operations over the read data to serve the service request. I am using Apache commons `FTPClient`.

As a temporary solution, I am creating an `FTPClient` object - then connecting it - and then logging in with the credentials - inside a method (the client is local to this method - doing this as `FTPClient` is not thread safe) in my data access layer and then disconnecting it before coming out of the methods(ie.. after reading the file). The issue is, `FTPClient` is taking some 3-7 seconds for logging in which is very high. So I am thinking of implementing an `FTPClientPool` that can provide an already prepared client in the data access method.

Do any such ClientPools already exist?

If yes, then what one should I opt for?

If no, the difficulty in implementing is once created and connected, How long does an apache FTPClient stay alive? for infinite time?? (what I mean is what is the default keep alive time for an FTPClient - idle time after which client gets disconnected - coz I see various kind of times in the java docs. :( ) And next  questions is How do you keep it alive always?? (may be sending the NOOPS after regular intervals in a separate thread??) Any kind of help regarding how should I move forward is really helpful.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 2):

Idle timeout for clients is generally determined server side.

Here's some of the more non obvious client parameters:

- soTimeout - Determines how long the client blocks waiting for a message. Generally you poll a socket every so often and this determines how long you wait during a poll.
- soLinger - Determines how long to keep the connection after close() has been called.

From my experience of using FTP, they normally just reconnect if the connection closes - it's not normally vital to have a constant uninterrupted connection unlike in other applications.

What are you using FTP for - it's normally not that time critical a service ...

Comment: Hi Philip, Thanks for your response. As I mentioned  - Data Access Layer in my REST Service talks with a FTP Server.And Time, is very important for me if not too critical.

Answer (score 1):

As for **ClientPools**, I happened to write a demo project.
[commons-pool-ftp](https://github.com/Honwhy/commons-pool-ftp)

I am getting a little bit annoyed by the ftp protocol,
in our experience, it would meet *broken pipe* when testing on the client that just getting from the pool.

`testOnBorrow=true`

Answer (score 0):

Configure

```
protected static ThreadLocal<FTPClient> ftpClientContainer = new 
ThreadLocal<>();
```

Then use:

```
//login() will be your login method to FTP:

ftpClientContainer.set(ftpLogin());
```

Then in each method add:

```
FTPClient ftpClient = ftpClientContainer.get();
```

and finely when done:

```
//ftpDisconnect () will be your disconnect method to FTP:

ftpDisconnect(ftpClientContainer.get());
```